# Do I connect to a database for data or add it into the App. Win8 App

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-8

I am interested to know if I design an Win8 App with a lot of data. Would I add this data to a database and add it to a web server or into the app. Or do I add it directly into the code?
There would be a lot of data an example is this:

Name:
Location:
Description:
Picture:

For each one there would be 3 example for different ages to make it more readable ie. 4-8, 8-12, 12+

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: This is very broad. Please try to be more specific and provide relevant code for what you have tried.

Comment: Thank you for replying. There is no code to give it is a general enquiry. I have code to connect an app to a SQL database, I also know how to add the data into the apps code itself. I am just asking generally should I add the data into the app or into a database and link the app to the database. There will be a lot of information.

Answer (score 0):

Consider "Separations of Concerns".

- Your Data Access Layer (aka: repository) should focus on data access and data storage.

Furthermore:

- Your app should be focused on application logic.
- Your UI should only present.
- Your UI Logic should manage UI states (i.e. state navigation and view navigation).
- Your Business Logic Layer should serve as a model for the real world problem your application is attempting to solve.

If you build your app using these layers, then each layer could potentially be tested in isolation of one another.

Ideally, production code should be testable code.
Thus, testable code usually has loosely-coupled modules that make up the overall soultion.